# How to run functions that take more than 10s on Vercel?

Tags: next.js, serverless, background-task

My app periodically runs a function which takes ~20 minutes to run.

This is fine in development. But when I deployed the app on Vercel, the function doesn't complete.

This is because Vercel allows up to 10s limit execution for functions. How can I run this function?

Comment: Am not sure you can run background jobs and event-driven functions with nextjs APIs. But you can host a small backend on another platform (heroku, railway, aws, gcloud) to run these background jobs and event-driven functions. So that your nextjs server side handers just call your micro backend APIs when there is the need to run background jobs or event driven processes

Comment: Alternatively you can check out this article on inngest on running nextjs functions in the background on vercel and netlify - https://www.inngest.com/blog/run-nextjs-functions-in-the-background

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not much you can do if you want to keep using nextjs with Vercel. You can host it in aws amplify, but by the time of this answer the lambda functions are not working out of the box with nextjs 12. There are others services out there to help you hosting it in aws, but honestly you should be better of either not using nextjs api routes or, if you really want to use it, create an external app for doing the long process, triggered by the nextjs functions, and request the results to this app or to some database straight from the client side.

This is Vercel's solution for the problem, which in this situation is not very helpfull
https://vercel.com/guides/what-can-i-do-about-vercel-serverless-functions-timing-out

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not correct as of October 2023.

You can increase the timeout to up to 5 minutes by exporting maxDuration from the function:

```js
export const maxDuration = 300 // set a custom timeout in seconds, maximum 5 minutes (300s)
```

Read more here: https://vercel.com/changelog/serverless-functions-can-now-run-up-to-5-minutes

Answer (score 0):

**With Pages Router (`/pages/api/my-function/handler.ts`):**

```
export const config = {
  maxDuration: 5, // 5 seconds
};

export default function handler(
  request: NextApiRequest,
  response: NextApiResponse,
) {
  response.status(200).json({});
}
```

**With App Router (`/app/api/my-function/route.ts`):**

```
export const maxDuration = 5; // 5 seconds
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

export function GET(request: Request) {
  return new Response('{}', { status: 200 });
}
```

If you want to override the maximum duration of a function for your whole project when using Vercel, you can do it in `vercel.json` (I think this is only valid for the App Router):

```
{
  "functions": {
    "app/api/**/*": {
      "maxDuration": 5
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about all this on the [official docs](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/configuring-functions/duration).